# What is the cleanest way to retrieve a list of application resources across modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework

First, some **context**:

I am currently working on a modular Zend Framework application using [Zend_Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.html). I wrote a custom module bootstrap that inserts custom resources into the [Module Resource Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html), for example a 'Widget' resource.

**Now, assuming the following structure:**

```
/application
/application/modules/foo/widget/Bar.php
/application/modules/baz/widget/Qux.php
```

**How would I be able to retrieve a list of *every available widget* in my application, preferably without traversing my entire directory structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a perfect solution to this. The best way I think is to have a standard way of 'registering' widgets in the respective module bootstraps, similar to how module-specific view helpers work.

Create a class for managing widgets which you instantiate in your main application bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initWidgets()
    {
        return new Yourapp_Widgets();
    }
}
```

and then in each module:

```
class Foo_Boostrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initWidgets()
    {
        $widgetManager = $this->getApplication()->getResource('widgets');
        $widgetManager->registerWidget('Foo_Bar');
    }
}
```

you could then have a method on the widget manager class to return all registered widgets.